# Ternary short circuit vs If short circuit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am trying to short circuit the code to return false with a ternary operator. My understanding was that the ternary had an implicit return and in this case would have the same result as the if statement below it. That would be to immediately return false if the two arrays.length do not match and to pass onto the following logic if they did. I would appreciate some explanation as I have tried to understand the difference but it does not make sense to me why this would not work.
`

```
function same(arrOne, arrTwo) {
// This ternary and if statement should do the same thing?

    // arrOne.length !== arrTwo.length ? false : {}

    if (arrOne.length !== arrTwo.length) {
        console.log(false)
        return false
    }

    let result = {}
    // append frequencies of numbers to result object
    arrOne.forEach((i) => {
        result[i] ? result[i]++ : (result[i] = 1)
    })
    // check to see if square matches root in object
    arrTwo.forEach((i) => {})
    console.log(result)
}

same([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 9]) // false lengths do not match
// same([1,2,3], [1,9]) // false
// same([1,2,1], [4,4,1]) // false frequency must be the same
```

`

I have tried to short circuit the function to return false with a ternary operator that tests the length of the two arrays taken as arguments if their lengths do not match. The code runs as if the ternary is doing nothing.

Comment: The ternary operator has nothing to do with the `return` statement.

Comment: A *ternary expression* always *results in* ("returns") a value. As opposed to an `if` statement, which does not result in any value ("returns nothing"). You seem to be confusing these two things?

Comment: Pointy, would you mind expanding your answer. Should i not expect the ternary to return false when the arrays lengths do not match and stop the function from proceeding onto the following code?

Comment: @deceze if that is the case. Then why does false not return in this snippet when using the ternary operator, but when i implicitly return false with an if condition it does? I thought the ternary returned implicitly, but what i don't understand is why the ternary does not short circuit the operation of the function in this case, but the if condition with what i am assuming is the exact same logic does. I'm a junior, so maybe i am not clearly stating what i mean enough, is there any clarifying information i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator does *not implicitly `return`*. Only a `return` statement returns from a function.

What you are probably confusing is that a ternary operator *returns a value*. As in, you can assign the result of a ternary expression to something:

```
var foo = bar ? 'baz' : 42;
```

This is what it means for the ternary operator to *return a value*. This does not mean that it will implicitly execute a `return` and stop a function from processing. It just returns a value the same way `1 + 2` returns a value (`3`).

A ternary operator isn't useful to *conditionally `return` from a function.* Even if a ternary expression would do what you think it does, it would *always* have to `return` or never; but you want to `return` only in certain conditions. E.g. with a ternary you can only do this:

```
return foo ? bar : baz;
```

You can decide *what* to `return` inline, you cannot decide *whether* to `return` or not.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying. In my case I thought that by returning the code block it would act in the same way as a pass would in python if the arrays were of the same length, and short circuit the function by returning false if they were not. Thank you for replying.